# Comparing distance of swing object in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of SwingObjects that are painted onto a JPanel. I am trying to compare which objects are the closest to each other and I don't really know how to approach this. I made a helper method that takes compares the current SwingObject with another.

```
public double distance(SwingObject obj2)
{
    int x1 = this.getX();
    int y1 = this.getY();
    int x2 = obj2.getX();
    int y2 = obj2.getY();

    double distance = Math.sqrt(((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)) + ((y2-y1)*(y2-y1)));
    return distance; 
}
```

And I have a comparer method that compares on current SwingObject to the rest.

```
public void closest(SwingObject c, ArrayList<SwingObject> swingList)
{
}
```

Is there a way to compare everything in the array list to each other and determine the shorts one relative to the current SwingObject c?

Comment: Can't you just loop through the List to get each object, and then inside that loop, loop through the List again to compare each object to every other object?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Comment: Hmm, im not comparing everything to each other rather I'm only comparing one to everything else. Like if I had {a, b, c, d} I would take a and compare it with b, c, d and see which one are the closets to a and makes one of the the closestSwingObject.

Comment: Tip: Add @KevinWorkman (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* a person of a new comment.  BTW - what is a `SwingObject`?  Oh never mind, answer in the form of a MCTaRE.

Comment: @helloMundo I'm not sure how what you described is any different from my suggestion of using a basic nested for loop.

Comment: @helloMundo: Also consider `Math.hypot()`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside closest, loop through all the SwingObjects in swingList, and store in a new List the distances from c to the elements of swingList. After that, sort that local List, and return it from closest.

There's also a possible problem with your distance function. X and Y locations of Swing components are relative to their parent container. So you'll want all the X and Y's be relative to each other, so use [SwingUtilities.convertPoint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#convertPoint%28java.awt.Component,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Component%29).